# INNER JOIN on a table using more than one column, rails associations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join

I have association in rails 3.2,

```
has_many :skills, :dependent => :destroy,
```

I wanted to add a join with a condition in the above association,

```
skills = user.skills.joins('INNER JOIN user_skills ON skills.id = user_skills.skill_id and skills.account_id = user_skills.account_id')
```

So instead of using user.skills.joins(). I only wanted to use user.skills. Scope is also one option but is it possible to add that in association.

I don't want this additional condition in WHERE clause. I want this to be in the INNER JOIN. (I am creating an index on that column account_id)

**existing query:**

```
SELECT skills.* FROM skills INNER JOIN user_skills ON skills.id = user_skills.skill_id WHERE skills.account_id = 1 AND skills.account_id = 1 AND user_skills.user_id = 1
```

**expected query:**

```
SELECT skills.* FROM skills INNER JOIN user_skills ON skills.id = user_skills.skill_id and skills.account_id =user_skills.account_id WHERE skills.account_id = 1 AND user_skills.user_id = 1
```

**Associations:**

```
skill

has_many :user_skills, :order => :rank
has_many :users, :through => :user_skills, :source => :user, :dependent => :destroy


user_skill

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :skill, :class_name => 'Skill'

user.rb

has_many :user_skills, :order => :rank, :class_name => 'UserSkill' , :foreign_key => "user_id"
has_many :skills, :through => :user_skills, :source => :skill, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_skills, :allow_destroy => true
```

Comment: Do you have a through association or you are using join table

Comment: I am doing it through association.

Comment: so you can pass this condition with through association

Comment: can you please post the model and associations for user, skills and user_skills

Comment: I have added that in the question